# Suggestion over a simple FAT16/FAT32 read/write implementation

Tags: filesystems, msp430, flash-memory

Folks

I am using `MSP430 and M25P64(serial flash memory)` .
I need suggestion for generic file system  that I can use to implement

Thanks
AK

Comment: This looks like a possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/657586.  It mentions YAFFS2, JFFS2, and FAT+FTL.  It's from 2009, so there have probably been some advances since then.

Answer (score 1):

I've used JFFS2 on serial flash devices before. It's not ideal (it's designed for NAND flash, whereas serial flash chips tend to be NOR), but it was easy on the platform I used.